# Display information in line graph using d3.js with Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, d3.js

This is my first time here, because I always find the answer I need in stackoverflow, but this time I have found some answers, but nothing work...

So, I am trying to use d3.js in my ruby project, but I have found problems to display a line graph in my project. I am using json data to create the graph, with 2 values (kilograms and dates), but I get the following error:

```
<path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,236.32LNaN,2…
```

The data is loaded from a JSON call in the controller with:

```
 format.json { render json: @kilograms }
```

@kilograms is a variable with a all method:

```
@kilograms = Kilogram.all
```

And this is the code in kilograms.js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  loadKilogramGraphic();
});


var loadKilogramGraphic = function() {
                        $.ajax({
                          type: 'GET',
                          url: '/kilograms',
                          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-
8',
                          dataType: 'json',
                          success: function(data){
                            drawKiloGraph(data);
                          },
                          failure: function(result){
                            error();
                          }
                        });
                      };

function error() {
    console.log("Something went wrong!");
} 


// set plot parameters
var width = 200;
var height = 280;

function drawKiloGraph(data) {

  var maxKilogram = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.kg });
  var maxDate = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.kg_date });
  var minDate = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.kg_date });



  function sortByDateAscending(a, b) {
    // Dates will be cast to numbers automagically:
    return a.kg_date - b.kg_date;
  }

  // scaling the graph
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                 .domain([0, maxKilogram])
                 .range([height, 0]);

  var x = d3.scaleTime()
                 .domain([minDate, maxDate])
                 .range([0, width]);

  // Adding the axis
  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

  // Adding svg in html
  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
              .attr('height', '100%')
              .attr('width', '100%');

  // Group in svg
  var chatGroup = svg.append('g')
                      .attr('transform', 'translate(100, 50)');

  // Puting data in line
  var line = d3.line()
                  .x(function(d){ return x([d.kg_date]);})
                  .y(function(d){ return y([d.kg]);});

  // Creating the path
  chatGroup.append("path").attr("d", line(data));
  chatGroup.append('g').attr('class', 'x axis')
                      .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 
                       220)').call(xAxis);
  chatGroup.append('g').attr('class', 'y axis').call(yAxis);


};
```

Thank you for taking your time! I am a junior!

Comment: Tough to answer without seeing your data (update your question with a snippet of it), but this looks suspect: `.x(function(d){ return x([d.kg_date]);})`; try just `x(d.kg_date)` and `y(d.kg)` [remove the brackets].

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have tried that, but it's not working...

Comment: The data is JSON file from the controller with a call in the controller      format.json { render json: @kilograms }

Answer (score 0):

Again, you haven't really shown us what the JSON looks like.  Assuming a structure like this:

```
var data = [{
  kg_date: new Date('2018-03-01'),
  kg: Math.random() * 10
}, {
  kg_date: new Date('2018-03-02'),
  kg: Math.random() * 10
}, {
  kg_date: new Date('2018-03-03'),
  kg: Math.random() * 10
}, {
  kg_date: new Date('2018-03-04'),
  kg: Math.random() * 10
}, {
  kg_date: new Date('2018-03-05'),
  kg: Math.random() * 10
}];
```

Your problem is indeed what I point out in my comments.  Further, the placement of your plot, margins, height and width is a bit off.  I generally start with [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) to get the basic positions correct.

All that said, here it is cleaned up:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // set plot parameters
    var width = 300;
    var height = 280;
    var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 40
    };

    var data = [{
      kg_date: new Date('2018-03-01'),
      kg: Math.random() * 10
    }, {
      kg_date: new Date('2018-03-02'),
      kg: Math.random() * 10
    }, {
      kg_date: new Date('2018-03-03'),
      kg: Math.random() * 10
    }, {
      kg_date: new Date('2018-03-04'),
      kg: Math.random() * 10
    }, {
      kg_date: new Date('2018-03-05'),
      kg: Math.random() * 10
    }];

    drawKiloGraph(data);

    function drawKiloGraph(data) {

      var maxKilogram = d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.kg
      });
      var maxDate = d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.kg_date
      });
      var minDate = d3.min(data, function(d) {
        return d.kg_date
      });

      function sortByDateAscending(a, b) {
        // Dates will be cast to numbers automagically:
        return a.kg_date - b.kg_date;
      }
      
      // Adding svg in html
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

      width = width - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // scaling the graph
      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, maxKilogram])
        .range([height, 0]);

      var x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([minDate, maxDate])
        .range([0, width]);

      // Adding the axis
      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

      // Group in svg
      var chatGroup = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

      // Puting data in line
      var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return x(d.kg_date);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return y(d.kg);
        });

      // Creating the path
      chatGroup.append("path").attr("d", line(data))
        .style('fill', 'none')
        .style('stroke', 'steelblue');

      chatGroup.append('g').attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height) + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

      chatGroup.append('g').attr('class', 'y axis').call(yAxis);

    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```